# How do I implement 'malloc', and 'fgets' to read and print the input stream

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

I have a challenge: ask user to input first, the maximum number of characters, then, input the string. Memory should be dynamically allocated and the string inputted should be printed.

My code;

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int size;
        char * pText = NULL;
        
        // get the maximum string length
        printf("\nEnter maximum length of string (a number): ");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        
        // allocate memory
        pText = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    
        if(pText != NULL)
        {
            // get user's input string
            printf("\nEnter your string:\n");
            fgets(pText, size, stdin);
    
            printf("\nThe input string is %s.\n", pText);
        
        }
    
        free(pText);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

This is all the code that there is. The problem I am experiencing is in the if-block; the originally implemented code is,

```c
    scanf(" ");
    gets(pText);

    printf("\nThe inputted string is %s.\n", *pText);
```

which is some wizardry that I believe removes terminating characters from `scanf`, enabling `gets` to read in a string along with terminating character (if I have the information correct); it has not been fully explained. While that implementation works, I have been told that it is possible to use `fgets` to implement the same functionality.

My attempt to implement `fgets` leads to the outcome where the user cannot input a string because the program terminates after the maximum number of characters (as an integer) has been entered and `<return>` has been pressed. I believe that because pText IS NULL, or zero, the program terminates before any text can be written.

I have tried reading around the subject of `fgets`, but most examples deal with accepting data from an input file, not `stdin`. I'm not sure what the problem is, or where I am going wrong, but I would appreciate some enlightenment.

Comment: Remember that strings are really named ***null-terminated** strings*. That means a string of size `X` needs `X + 1` elements to fit the terminator. Also note that `fgets` will add the ending newline if it can fit (which `gets` will not do).

Comment: And never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that it has been removed from the C standard.

Comment: Before you continue, "pointers are arrays"? No that's not true. A pointer can point to the first element of an array, but it's not an array in itself. And arrays can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but an array isn't a pointer in itself.

Comment: As for your question, "it does not work" is just not enough of a problem description. ***How*** doesn't it work? What happens? What is supposed to happen? For some specified input what is the expected and actual output? Please take some time to refresh [ask] and [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: `Enter maximum number of characters: 8abcdefgh`

Comment: But that doesn't match the code you show? In the code you show you will never call `fgets` with a null-pointer `pText`. Are you asking why you can't pass a null pointer to `fgets`, with some code you don't show us? Or are you asking about some other problem with the code you actually show?

Comment: @user3121023 That loop could become infinite if there's an error or if the user presses the "end of file" key instead.

Comment: Don't forget that [`scanf()` leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer) so the first string read will be "empty".

Comment: You shouldn't pass a null pointer to `fgets`. It doesn't have null-pointer checks and will happily dereference the pointer to store the data it reads without concern of pointer validity. If you get build-error then please create a proper [mcve] replicating the errors, and show it to us together with a full and complete copy-paste of the errors you get. I suggest you post it as a new question and delete this one (unless this have helped you in other ways). `fgets` is almost a drop-in replacement for `gets`, but with additional arguments making it safer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Perhaps I started my query completely on the wrong foot; I am learning C via an online course. I am not a developer (yet). I am trying to understand abstruse explanations within the course (or none at all and having to guess, or work hard to find answers). I am happy to receive comments, but I am at fault for commentors' assumption of my level of proficiency; forgive me.

Comment: My advice for you is to invest in some books. Even rather bad books are typically better than a mediocre online-tutorial. And of course taking classes with teachers and other students is even better, as it allows better interaction with your teacher and a more tight-knit group of like-minded students. But books is really a must in my opinion. And the books doesn't have to be brand new, anything written in the last 15-20 years should suffice (as long as it includes the C99 standard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mixing `scanf` and `fgets` in the same program. It is possible, but only to cautious programmers because `scanf` stops reading as soon as it could complete its conversion or find an error.

So when your user type <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>, scanf reads the 1 and 0 characters (to form 10) **and leaves a `'\n'` character in the input buffer**. On next `fgets`, you immediately get an empty line and normally exit the program saying that nothing was read.

You should at least clean the input buffer up to the end of line:

```
scanf("%d", &size);
while (((int c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (c != EOF));  // read up to the end of line
```

That should be enough to fix the read problem, but you should considere controlling the return value or `scanf` and the validity of size (what for `xyz` or `-1` as input?).

Then if you want `fgets` to correctly return a line up to `size` useful characters, you should give it a buffer of `size + 2` characters, with a place for the newline and the terminating null (BTW `sizeof(char)` is `1` per standard).

```
// allocate memory
pText = (char *)malloc(size + 2);     // do not forget the new line and the null
```

Finally, you can get rid of the newline with `strcspn`

```
    fgets(pText, size, stdin);
    pText[strcspn(pText, "\r\n")] = '\0';  // remove the optional end of line
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. As the challenge is an exercise to fimiliarise one with ```malloc``` and pointers, I appreciate your walk-through of issues and solutions. There are, of course, functions that you have introduced, which are new to me. ```fgetc``` being one; could I have implemented something like, ```while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && (c != EOF));```? Also new to me is ```strcspn```; I understand how it functions, but I'm not sure I completely understand how you have implemented it. Nonetheless, and again, thank you.

Comment: @Den: In fact, `getchar()` is `fgetc(stdin)`. That means that `fgetc` extracts one character from a stream, while `getchar` extracts it from `stdin`. `strcspn` is one of the functions from the C Standard Library, declared in `string.h`. When unsure of what a standard function does, you can always consult the excellent [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/)

Comment: Thank you for confirming the substitute code works just as well, and thank you for the link to the resource - now bookmarked.